Build Error: Cython Compilation Fails After Installing Python 3.9 and Switching Between Python Versions in Virtual Environments
After installing Python 3.9 alongside Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04, and switching between Python versions in different virtual environments, the workspace build in ROS2 Foxy fails with a Cython-related compilation error. This error did not occur before the installation of Python 3.9. It seems like, for some reason, the build-process wants to use Python3.9 even if the venv and everything else is using Python3.8 ...
Steps to Reproduce:

Install Python 3.9 with adding the PPA for deadsnakes:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9

Configure Python Alternatives



Ensure that Python 3.8 remains the default Python version and Python 3.9 is set as a manual alternative:
sudo update-alternatives --configure python3

The output should show Python 3.8 as a selected option with manual mode, and Python 3.9 available as an alternative. Similar to this:

     **But with a * in front of the first Selection (python 3.8 - manual mode)**




Create and Activate a Virtual Environment with Python 3.9:
sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
python3.9 -m venv venvPython39
source venvPython39/bin/activate

Install a Python 3.9 Package (I used pip)

Switch Back to Python 3.8 Virtual Environment



Deactivate the Python 3.9 virtual environment :
deactivate
Activate the normal virtual Environment with Python 3.8
source /path/to/your/python3.8-venv/bin/activate


Attempt to Build the Workspace (just a normal Package which worked before all the steps with Python 3.8)
colcon build

What I've tried so far

checked if the Python versions are correct (with python3 -V) in both venvs

Reinstalled cython & numpy in both venvs (with pip install --upgrade cython numpy)

checked echo $PYTHONPATH, echo $PATH

cleaned the workspace before building (with rm -rf build/ install/ log/)

checked the setup.py of the Python3.8-package, if there is something connected to Python3.9

I checked the environment parameters with env | grep -i python

I checked setup.py with cd ~/ros2_ws/src/packagename and python3 setup.py install => there was no error!

I created an isolated workspace of the Python3.8-Package:
mkdir -p ~/isolated_ws/src
cp -r ~/ros2_ws/src/pc2objectlist ~/isolated_ws/src/
cd ~/isolated_ws
source ~/ros2_ws/venv/bin/activate
colcon build


That workes without any errors! Why does the isolated workspace work?
Some other Information

My ROS2-Workspace "ros2_ws" consists of 2 packages "Package1" (Python 3.8) and "Package2" (Python 3.9) and 2 virtual environments, made with venv, "venv1" (Python 3.8) and "venv2" (Python 3.9).


Some parts of the error:

Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: src/cython/MD5.c: In function
'__pyx_pw_6pycrypt_3MD5_1new':


gcc -pthread -B /usr/local/miniconda3/envs/py38/compiler_compat
-Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=native -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/cython/MD5.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/cython/MD5.o


src/cython/MD5.c:212:31: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete
type 'PyInterpreterState'


CMake Error at
ament_cmake_python/cmake/ament_python_install_package.cmake:86
(message): Failed to install package 'examples_rclpy_minimal_service'.
Command '['/usr/bin/python3.9', 'setup.py', 'egg_info', '--egg-base',
'build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

